# modal view controller's frame size is not correctly assigned when it is launched from an UIPopOverController

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

I am implementing an in app browser which acts as a browser and it is presented modally from an UIViewController.

My issue is particularly in case of iPad.

I launch the browser control from a view controller on the root view controller or
detail view controller of a split view controller.

When I launch from detail or root view controller everything works as expected.

But when I launch the browser controller from a view controller on the UIPopOver controller
the browser's frame goes out of bound in landscape mode, 
but in case of portrait mode it works as expected.

Can you help me?
What am i doing wrong?

Here is the code:-

```
    BrowserController *browserController = [BrowserController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:browserController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want the view controller inside of a UIPopoverController to present a modal view controller. Instead, you most likely want your window's root view controller to present it. How you get at the appropriate view controller is up to you. Here is one way to do it:

```
id <UIApplicationDelegate> delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIViewController *rootViewController = [[delegate window] rootViewController];
BrowserController *browserController = [[BrowserController alloc] init];
[rootViewController presentModalViewController:browserController animated:YES];
[browserController release];
```